# Mount host docker with jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, devops

I need to mount host docker with Jenkins container, but problem is docker file is mounted as directory and I can't run docker commands inside Jenkins container.

I am using following command

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d \                                                            -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home/ \ -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ -v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker jenkins/jenkins:lts`

What I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

I also tried to use --mount instead of --volume/-v flag

Answer (score 1):

> ***Don't mount the volume to the host fil***e. This is not recommended and cause permission issue. Use the `--privileged` flag instead like this.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -d \
  --privileged \
  -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home/ \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Comment: Same issue after using --privileged flag. Docker file still mounted as directory within container.

Comment: Did you use it as I suggested? With new mount method

Comment: Yes, I did it as you suggested